# closure returning a reference does not compile due to lifetime

Tags: rust

I am trying to implement a generic function that amongst other things filters non-unique values from a vector by some arbitrary condition. I am using the method unique_by from itertools that accepts a closure, which in my case returns a reference to some data to compare.

```
use itertools::Itertools;
use std::hash::Hash;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Person {
    uints: Vec<usize>,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Dog {
    ints: Vec<i8>,
}

fn filter_duplicates(population: &[Person]) -> Vec<Person> {
    population
        .iter()
        .unique_by(|x| &x.uints)
        .cloned()
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
}

fn filter_duplicates_generic<T: Clone, V: Eq + Hash, F: Fn(&&T) -> V>(
    population: &[T],
    unique_representation: F,
) -> Vec<T> {
    population
        .iter()
        .unique_by(unique_representation)
        .cloned()
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
}

fn main() {
    let people = vec![
        Person {
            uints: vec![0, 1, 2],
        },
        Person {
            uints: vec![0, 1, 2],
        },
        Person {
            uints: vec![3, 4, 5],
        },
    ];

    let dogs = vec![Dog { ints: vec![0] }];

    // works.
    filter_duplicates(&people);

    // fails not compile.
    filter_duplicates_generic(&people, |x| &x.uints);
    filter_duplicates_generic(&dogs, |x| &x.ints);
}
```

When writing the closure directly inside the method, everything works perfectly, however when passing the closure from outside, I get a compilation error:

```
lifetime may not live long enough
returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
main.rs(45, 64): has type `&&'1 Person`
main.rs(45, 65): return type of closure is &'2 std::vec::Vec<usize>
```

I tried specifying lifetimes but failed to do so in a productive manner. why can itertools accept this type of closure into their method "unique_by" yet I cannot accept one into my own function "filter_duplicates_generic"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of `&&`, Rust can't automatically apply the same lifetime to all references in your function signature. You must do it manually.

```rust
fn filter_duplicates_generic<'a, T: Clone, V: Eq + Hash, F: Fn(&&'a T) -> V>(
    population: &'a [T],
    unique_representation: F,
) -> Vec<T> {
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7568e0e3281357ba7ddbc28c87cf1cb4)

Comment: No need to add `+'a` onto `V`

Comment: Thanks, seems like I still don't really understand the concept of lifetimes, back to the book I guess...

Comment: @cafce25 Fixed, thanks.